# x64 Portable Executable section order

Tags: 64-bit, portable-executable

Can the 3 essential sections: .data (resources), .rdata (imports), and .text (instructions) in the Portable Executable (.exe) file format be in any order as long as the 'Address of Entry Point' field points to the .text section?  It seems like having the instructions (.text) be first is a big pain in the butt since you have to calculate the imports and resources sections to actually WRITE the instructions section...

This is what I'm going off of: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKwgd.jpg

What about for run-time performance?

Comment: Could you be more precise about what your concerns are regarding run-time performance?

Comment: If I switch up the order of the sections (assuming it works), will it take more time for the executable loader to load the sections into memory and start the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already answered by [Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29424359/2646573), the linker is free to arrange sections in any order, as seen best fit. The only exception is named sections like `.text$A` and `.text$B`, where the sections *must* be sorted in lexicographical order according to the suffix following the `$`.

The order in which the sections are written by the linker is not of great significance to how easy it is to produce the final binary, either. Typically, the binary file isn't written sequentially as the sections are computed; rather, the section contents are produced in buffers, and the references between code and data are kept symbolic (in a relocatable format) until the sections are written to the final executable.

The part of the question relating to performance has more to do with how the *image loader* in Windows works, rather than the *linker*. Because the loader does not need the sections in any particular order, there is no additional overhead (e.g. related to sorting) when unpacking the sections into the memory view of the image file. Relocations and matching between import and export tables are done in any case, and the amount of work is decided by other factors. Hence, the order decided by the linker does not in itself affect the loading time.

For normal Windows API or Native binaries (not CLR), the section names are not important either--only the [*characteristics*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680341(v=vs.85).aspx) of each section, which decide e.g. the access rights of the memory mapped pages in the image (whether they are read-only, writable, executable, etc.). For example, the import table may be placed in a section named `.idata` rather than `.rdata`, or the section may be named something completely different.

Answer (score 3):

The format of a PE file is described in detail by the [pecoff.doc document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/b/a/eba1050f-a31d-436b-9281-92cdfeae4b45/pecoff.doc) (direct link to a Word2003 file).  What you are asking about is covered in chapter 4, it talks about the Section Table.  The most relevant detail:

> The number of entries in the Section Table is given by the NumberOfSections field in the file header. Entries in the Section Table are numbered starting from one. The code and data memory section entries are in the order chosen by the linker.

So no, this is not cast in stone, sections can appear in any order.

> It seems like having the instructions (.text) be first is a big pain

As hinted by the pecoff language, it is a linker implementation detail.  And to Microsoft's linker, and probably most any other linker, it is not actually a big pain.  It's first and foremost job is to generate the executable code and there tends to be a lot of it.  And not all of the code is used, just what is needed to resolve the dependencies.  Which is a *very* common scenario, a static C runtime library would be a classic example.  Your program does not call every possible runtime function, the linker only links in what is needed.

Details like relocations and imports are a minor detail, there are just not nearly as many of them.  So it is a lot more efficient to *first* generate the code and keep track of the required relocations and imports to match that code in memory, to write them to the PE file later.

Your assumption that it is "better" the other way around is not accurate.  To a linker anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The only impact here may be of distance between import and code address, so that shorter jump instructions may be used. Though it is negligible difference.